# Which is best way to update a high nested MongoDb document?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, operators

I'm working in a survey system, using Nodejs, Mongoose and MongoDb.

When a user add a vote I need to update a high level of nesting parameter.

About 500 people will vote every second.

Is there a way to performantly access to the "votes" node and sum an integer?

```
survey { // Level 1
    title,
    description,
    content
        [ // Array of objects Level 2
            { 
                id_options
                options: [ // Array of objects level 3
                    {
                        id_votes
                        votes //<<< Value to update with votes + 1
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use $update in an aggregation - note that you will need to $unwind your arrays of documents.